# Formatar estrutura de texto html do mesmo formato que um aarquivo Word

Tags: html, css, angular-8, angular-cli

Estou pesquisando mais não estou conseguindo encontrar nada parecido. Criar um modal com uma estrutura de contrato de serviço baseado em um word.

Como tentativas copie esse texto direto para meu conteudo html. Porem ele não fica nada parecido com a formatação do word. Poderia partir por estruturar esse html com suas devida propriedade ate deixar ele parecido com que existe no word, o que nao seria dificl porem extenso sa que se trata de 18 paginas.

Unico porem é que tenho varios tipos de contratos que podem ser exibidos. Ou seja teria qye fazer algo dinamico ao ponte dele conseguir pegar o texto em worde mostrar para o usuario em uma formatação agradavel e entendivel.

Existe algum tipo de display ou component que consiga exibir esse aquivo word ?